# db.create_all()を用いたデータベースの作成が出来ない

Tags: python, sql, database, flask, sqlalchemy

動画を参考に、Pythonを用いたtodolistのwebアプリ開発講座において、以下のコード (app.py) を作成し、

```
>>> from app import db
>>> db.create_all()
```

のコマンドを打つことでデータベースの作成を行いたいのですが、何度やってもうまくいきません。(動画では18分目ぐらいからの内容)

**参考にした動画:**
[Python(Flask)×Webアプリ開発入門コース (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jP7p2okKdJA)

#### 気になる点

以下に示すapp.pyにおいて「Column」「Integer」「String」「DateTime」において

**クラス 'SQLAlchemy' の未解決の属性参照 'Column' **

が警告文として出ている点が原因かなと思いました。

#### 試したこと

- 警告文の検索
- SQLAlchemyのバージョンを下げて再インストール(1.3.20よりバージョンが上では通らないことがあるため)

#### バージョン

editor:pycharm
interpreter:3.8
OS:windows10
SQLAlchemy:1.3.20

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

---

#### ソースコード

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///todo.db"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    detail = db.Column(db.String(100))
    due = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: こちら [【保存版】30分でFlask入門！Webアプリの作り方をPythonエンジニアが解説](https://tech-diary.net/flask-introduction/) にテキストの記事があるようなので、併せて見て違いを探してみてはどうでしょう？